# C2DM registration results never receive

Tags: response, registration, android-c2dm

I have used "Android Cloud to Device Messaging (C2DM) - Tutorial" by Lars Vogel.
When i start my applcation, registration response never received.
How It can be solved?
my Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/appicon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">

    <activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
              android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".ui.DailyTripList" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name=".ui.TripActivity"  android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name=".ui.StationsList"  android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name=".ui.StationActivity"  android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name=".ui.PassengerList"  android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name=".ui.DriverMsgList"  android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <service android:name=".services.SecurityReqestTransmitter" android:exported="false"/>
    <service android:name=".services.LocationTransmitter" android:exported="false"/>
    <activity android:name=".cardReader.IDTUniMagActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.C2DMBroadcastReceiver" 
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      <!-- Receive the actual message -->
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
          <category android:name="com.em_projects.MyWay.receivers" />
      </intent-filter>
      <!-- Receive the registration id -->
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
          <category android:name="com.em_projects.MyWay.receivers" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

CatLog

```
 08-15 23:57:41.624: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(959): No keyboard for id 0
08-15 23:57:41.634: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(959): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
08-15 23:57:44.645: DEBUG/dalvikvm(150): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 698 objects / 37712 bytes in 273ms
08-15 23:58:01.374: DEBUG/SntpClient(70): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
08-15 23:58:17.365: INFO/EventLogService(236): Aggregate from 1313450896472 (log), 1313450896472 (data)
08-15 23:58:22.704: DEBUG/dalvikvm(236): GC_EXPLICIT freed 473 objects / 120056 bytes in 276ms
08-15 23:58:29.744: DEBUG/dalvikvm(150): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 611 objects / 29936 bytes in 198ms
08-15 23:58:32.754: DEBUG/MainActivity(959): onClick
08-15 23:58:33.944: INFO/global(959): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
08-15 23:58:33.974: DEBUG/Communicator(959): @ parseData <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root><row internal_code="644" external_code="1442" ws_string="http://wap.y-it.co.il:8080/wapdb/ws_redirect/http://localhost:8080/fltctrl_11" report_location_period="60" reject_mission="1"/></root>
08-15 23:58:34.124: DEBUG/MainActivity(959): Rows counter = 1
08-15 23:58:34.155: DEBUG/MainActivity(959): handleMessage
08-15 23:58:34.184: INFO/ActivityManager(70): Starting activity: Intent { flg=0x4000000 cmp=com.em_projects.MyWay/.ui.DailyTripList }
08-15 23:58:34.494: DEBUG/DailyTripList(959): onCreate
08-15 23:58:35.444: DEBUG/dalvikvm(959): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 7436 objects / 493624 bytes in 90ms
08-15 23:58:43.254: ERROR/C2DMRegistrar(236): [C2DMReg] handleRequest caught java.io.IOException: SSL shutdown failed: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe
08-15 23:58:43.534: DEBUG/SecurityReqestTransmitter(959): onCreate
08-15 23:58:43.584: DEBUG/SecurityReqestTransmitter(959): initServiceThread
08-15 23:58:43.624: DEBUG/SecurityReqestTransmitter(959): run
08-15 23:58:43.634: DEBUG/SecurityReqestTransmitter(959): onStartCommand
08-15 23:58:43.875: DEBUG/LocationTransmitter(959): onCreate
08-15 23:58:43.944: DEBUG/LocationTransmitter(959): spd = 0.0
08-15 23:58:44.024: WARN/GpsLocationProvider(70): Duplicate add listener for uid 10040
08-15 23:58:44.224: WARN/ActivityManager(70): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
08-15 23:58:44.414: INFO/global(959): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
08-15 23:58:44.454: WARN/ActivityManager(70): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{44ec58c0 com.em_projects.MyWay/.ui.DailyTripList}
08-15 23:58:44.534: DEBUG/Communicator(959): @ parseData <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root><row line_code="90476" acc_name="אי סי אי" order_start_time="08:00" order_end_time="08:30" line_description="איסוף עובדים איזור הדרום" line_status="-1" t_Pass_QTY="4" Pass_QTY="4" group_name="שם הקבוצה" department_name="שם המחלקה" line_date="2011-08-15" long_remarks="הערות ארוכות...&#x0D;&#x0A;שורה שניה&#x0D;&#x0A;שורה שלישית&#x0D;&#x0A;שורה רביעית&#x0D;&#x0A;שורה אחרונה !" short_remarks="הערות קצרות של הנסיעה"/><row line_code="90377" acc_name="מפעל תע&quot;ש רכש" order_start_time="12:00" order_end_time="12:45" line_description="מרוחובות+נס ציונה לתע&quot;ש" line_status="-1" t_Pass_QTY="0" Pass_QTY="0" line_date="2011-08-15" long_remarks="" short_remarks=""/><row line_code="90406" acc_name="משתלת ציפורן" order_start_time="15:00" order_end_time="15:40" line_description="הסעות עובדים אמצע שבוע" line_status="5" t_Pass_QTY="0" Pass_QTY="0" department_name="מחלקה 1" line_date="2011-08-15" long_remarks="על הנהג להתקשר לשלמה 050-3344334 בעל המשתלה&#x0D;&#x0A;כל יום לאחר סיום ההסעה." short_remarks="הערה ליום ב&#39;"/><row line_code="90439" acc_name="טבע כפר סבא" order_start_time="18:00" order_end_time="18:00" line_description="נתב&quot;ג כ&quot;ס" line_status="-1" t_Pass_QTY="0" Pass_QTY="0" line_date="2011-08-15" long_remarks="" short_remarks=""/></root>
08-15 23:58:47.554: INFO/ActivityManager(70): Displayed activity com.em_projects.MyWay/.ui.DailyTripList: 13122 ms (total 13122 ms)
```

Comment: How far through the `C2DMBaseReceiver` process do you get?

Comment: I think `ERROR/C2DMRegistrar(236)` is your problem - SSL issues aren't so much fun to fix :(

Comment: How it can be fixed? any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your app package name `com.em_projects.MyWay.receivers`?
If no, try to use only your package name instead of `com.em_projects.MyWay.receivers` in categories

```
<receiver android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.C2DMBroadcastReceiver" 
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
  <!-- Receive the actual message -->
  <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
      <category android:name="***your_app_package_name***" />
  </intent-filter>
  <!-- Receive the registration id -->
  <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
      <category android:name="***your_app_package_name***" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```